# Windows azure management portal not showing data and api option on creating mobile services.

Tags: sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

all the tutorial videos  of azure shows the data tab in mobile services but in real it is not present there.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhoXvChLA34dDB1Mm1KVFIwRUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the information contained in the google drive inline in the question itself? It is a protected resource which most people don't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the .NET backend, creating tables and custom APIs are done code first and you can't control them via the portal.

For tables start here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-data/

I don't see any tutorials up yet on the custom API path yet but I may have missed them.